# Why does std::any implementation use typeid?

Tags: c++, optimization, rtti, libc++, stdany

It seems that `std::any` [works just fine](https://godbolt.org/z/x8b1aq) in GCC and Clang even when compiling with  -fno-rtti.

While looking at the libc++ source I see that they just use a simple trick:

they take the address of a variable templated on a type in any so that is how they get the unique id.

But this code is active only when there is no RTTI turned on.

That got me wondering. Why do they even use RTTI in the first place? Why not always use this solution?
I have no idea why `typeid` would be faster than simple pointer (to a static variable that is instantiated per type) comparisons.

Comment: It might be to support polymorphic types where the type of the variable doesn't match the type of the object

Comment: @AlanBirtles you mean something like this? It does not seem to work even with RTTI https://godbolt.org/z/MEc3vb

Comment: Could you please give a link to where the implementation uses RTTI?

Comment: @xskxzr you mean this? https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/libcxx/include/any

Comment: I guess standard forces them to. [link](https://eel.is/c++draft/any.nonmembers#lib:any_cast) . any::type() needs to return type_info and any_cast throws bad_­any_­cast if "operand.type() != typeid(remove_­reference_­t<T>)".

Comment: @jannarc Does the other solution without `typeid` have the same observable behavior? If so, since the "as-if" rule, the other solution is definitely OK.

Comment: MSVC STL also uses typeid https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/master/stl/inc/any and the code also compiles without RTTI https://godbolt.org/z/saG81M